# Foreign Key could not be found with SqlAlchemy and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I just started a Flask - SqlAlchemy project and am having some trouble with Foreign Keys.

I have the tables User and Portfolio. Portfolio has a foreign key to user, using username. I set up my model like this.

```
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'portfolio_users'
  __table_args__ = {"schema":"keldan"}
  username = Column(String(), primary_key=True)
  date_added = Column(DateTime())

class Portfolio(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'portfolios'
  __table_args__ = {"schema":"keldan"}
  id = Column('pid', Integer(), Sequence('portfolios_pid_seq'), primary_key=True)
  date_added = Column(DateTime())
  name = Column(String())
  username = Column(String(), ForeignKey('portfolio_users.username'))
  user = relationship('User', backref=backref('portfolios', cascade='save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan'))
```

The error I get when I try to run a simple select all query is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'portfolios.username' could not find table 'portfolio_users' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'username'
```

The tables are created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE keldan.portfolio_users
(
  username text NOT NULL,
  date_added date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE keldan.portfolios
(
  pid serial NOT NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  date_added date NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT portfolios_pk PRIMARY KEY (pid),
  CONSTRAINT portfolios_fk FOREIGN KEY (username)
      REFERENCES keldan.portfolio_users (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I have spent the better part of a day trying to figure this out or making workarounds using primaryjoin but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/172)

If you are not using the default schema (public) then it's not enough to specify the schema for each class, but I need to specify it in the foreign key as well.

```
username = Column(String(), ForeignKey('keldan.portfolio_users.username'))
```